# ssh can access master but not the devices connected to the master

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, bashrc, ros

Hi im trying to connect to the master computer using ssh (linksys-wify), its not showing any errors when connecting, but when trying to see the list of devices connected in my master computer using ssh from my laptop its not showing any of the devices connected like cameras or arduino.

[image]

Comment: `ls` lists directories.  `lshw` is how you list your hardware devices in the system.

Comment: There is no error, since you're running the wrong command.